# Facebook Graph permissions incorrect

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to update my code to work with the FB Graph 3.0.

The login flow works fine, and I request my permissions and the user grants them. The later bit of PHP code that uses the PHP SDK is meant to post to the user's timeline.

```
$r = $this->facebook->get('/me/permissions');
$result = $this->facebook->post('/me/feed/', $fbpost);
```

If I examine `$r`, I can see that I have the permissions required:

```
manage_pages: granted
publish_pages: granted
public profile: granted
pages_show_list: granted
```

Yet when it makes the actual request, it fails with an error: `(#200) Requires either publish_actions permission, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission`

When I attempt to add the `publish_actions` grant to my login (using the javascript library) I get an error that it's invalid: `Invalid Scopes: publish_actions.` despite FB's own documentation showing this exact scope in several example.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: I'm not all that concerned with the `publish_actions` scope having changed, though I understand that may be a new change that isn't in the docs-- but I do have the `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` permissions, yet I still can't post to my timeline, and the error code seems to say that those permissions are not set.

Comment: It was just announced that it was removed. Probably some documentation have not been updated

Comment: You can not post to user timelines via API any more in v3.0, only to page timelines. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#login-4-24

Comment: _“but I do have the manage_pages and publish_pages permissions, yet I still can't post to my timeline, and the error code seems to say that those permissions are not set”_ - which most likely means, you did not use a page token to begin with, but only your user access token, which means `/me` would point to your personal profile, and not the page to begin with.

Comment: Remind me of something else: for some weeks it's impossible to share links of page publications for some unknown permission reason. Were you trying to post on your feed a sharing of a page publication ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a FB API expert, however, Twitter recently removed the ability to post automatically to FB-- my assumption is that this automated posting to a user's timeline is no longer possible in the latest FB graph API. At least, it takes a lot more hoops to jump through than a 3rd party developer can expect a non-technical customer to handle.

https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/link-twitter-to-facebook

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [FB v3.0 API /me/feed endpoint documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.0/user/feed#publish) you need the `user_posts` permission (which isn't listed in your granted permissions) to read and publish on this endpoint. Publish_x permissions are only related to pages and group, not personnal feed.

Also check the board of your FB App if there are no review alerts, with the recent changes in legislation (GDPR ...) and Facebook issues (Cambridge Analytica etc...) a lot of changes has been made in the API.